# CSS transition flickers with a:visited in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, but not Opera

Tags: css, anchor, css-transitions

(For browsers that support CSS transitions, including the latest versions of Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. Strangely, this issue does not appear in Opera.)

Has anyone else noticed this? When you put a color transition on a:link, the a:visited transitions to the a:link color before displaying the a:hover color. Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mgzv9/2/

Can this color flicker be avoided?

Comment: And the latest Chrome doesn't even do transitions on visited links...

Answer (score 1):

I have been banging my head around this problem for a while.

The thing is, that this problem is actually hard to reproduce.

OK, so what happens, sometimes while loading/refreshing a page with color transition on links,  the color is first transitioned from the default browser link color, to the CSS defined color. It actually doesn't happen for me, when I open the HTML from disk, but if I put it in a server (even local server), then this problem shows up.

To reproduce the problem, create an HTML, add a stylesheet and define a transition for links, something like this:

```
a {
  color: red;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .5s linear;
    -o-transition: color .5s linear;
    -ms-transition: color .5s linear;
    transition: color .5s linear;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

...and then include the stylesheet in your HTML.

Put the files on a server, and try opening the page in Chrome, try refreshing the site, sometimes you should first see a transition from the default blue color, when the pages loads.

After deconstructing some sites, where there seemed to be no problem with this, I came up with this simple solution.

If you include some Javascript files too, then just place Javascript includes **AFTER** your CSS includes.

It even work if you just include an empty JS file, after you stylesheet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How interesting. I am not finding your Javascript fix makes any difference. Check out soulmastery.net, for example. I'm also not finding any difference between viewing local files and server files. Issue remains in Safari 5.1.2 and Firefox 8.0.1 (running OS X Lion). Fortunately, it appears Chrome has fixed the issue (in 15.0.874.121).

Comment: The bug/feature (hard to say because it's obviously a result of some intended behaviour) is still present as of Chrome 25 and FF 24 - but the fix WORKS. I put my JS *out of head tag*, (and you should certainly put it *after css link*) - and it works! quote: "Anything in the head must be completed before the body is loaded, so it is generally a bad idea to put javascript in there. If you need something while the body is loading, or want to expedite some ajax, then it would be appropriate to put it in the head." This goes for e.g. wp_head() [WordPress], which should go *just before </head>*.

Answer (score 0):

I never seen it happen while using color. But yea it happens when using images in baground.This is bcoz of the loading time, and can be avoided by using all the transition images in one big image and use baground-position property to control the image.

Comment: It happens in three of the latest browsers; check out the JSFiddle.